# Attraction between two objects in the universe. The resulting number of forces between them

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics

Right now I am studying Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation and I already learned his Third Law. It is said that there is an action-reaction pair between the falling apple and the Earth which results in the apple being attracted to the Earth and Earth to the apple at the same time and with the same force. But if we imagine bigger objects like Earth and Mars in the close distance, will it mean that Earth attracts to Mars and Mars is being attracted to the Earth with **the gravitational force of Earth** and at the same time Mars attracts to Earth and Earth to Mars because of **Mars gravitational force**. So as a result I counted 4 forces between two objects. Is it correct or not, and please explain why :)

Comment: What makes you think there is any difference between the apple-earth  and Mars-earth  examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only the one gravitational interaction. You can describe it however many ways you like, but the physical interaction is only happening once.

If you want to know how two objects will move because of a force between them, relative to a distant inertial observer, calculate the change of their relative velocity by picking whatever frame measures the acceleration due to gravity that you want to integrate over time, then conserve momentum in the distant inertial frame.

For example: Bob and Alice are standing together on some frictionless ice. Bob (mass $m_B$) pushes on Alice (mass $m_A$) such that Alice has a velocity of $v$ relative to Bob. Conserve momentum $P_0$ in the frame in which you want to measure Alice's and Bob's velocity. (If this is the frame in which Alice and Bob were initially standing still, $P_0 = 0$.)

$P_0 = m_A v_a + m_Bv_b$

$v = v_a - v_b$

Solve for $v_a$ and $v_b$ in terms of $v, m_A, m_B, P_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in the universe attracts every other object in the universe by gravity.$^1$   Even every part of every object attracts all the other parts. That is what holds the Earth together despite it being a pressure cooker of magma on the inside.  The reason we can ignore the Moon and Mars when predicting what the apple wil do is that Newton's formula for gravity is:

$$ F = \frac{M_1×M_2}{R^2}   $$

The force is found by multiplying the masses of objects 1 and 2, and dividing by the distance $R$ between them *squared*.  The squared means that the force of gravity decreases rapidly with distance on astronomical scales. If you double the distance, the force decreases by $\frac 1 4$.  If you increase the distance by 10x, the force decreases by $\frac 1 {100}$.

Now Earth and Mars are very roughly the same mass, but you are 3900 miles from the center of the Earth, while you are 183 million miles from the center of Mars. So Mars is 47,000 times further away, making its attractive force $1/(47,000)^2$ or $1/(2,200,000,000)$ as strong as the Earth's. So both you and the apple can safely ignore it.

$$\\$$

$^1$ Limited by the speed of light.  There is a long delay in the interaction with objects that are far apart. Earth is not attracted by the matter beyond the observable universe (as it is now) and never will be.

$^2$ Yes, $G=1$ for pedagogical reasons.